# Getter and setter findbugs May expose internal representation

Tags: java, intellij-idea, findbugs

I just started using Firebug in my IntelliJ project.

```
private byte[] image;

public byte[] getImage() {
    return image;
}

public void setImage(byte[] image) {
    this.image = image;
}
```

Firebug gives me the error :

```
May expose internal representation by incorporating reference to mutable object
```

I really don't understand what the error means and how I can mitigate it.

### EDIT

I also get this error with my constructor:

```
public Design(byte[] image){
    this.image = image;
}
```

I fixed the error on the Getter thanks to a post and understand what it means, But the errors on the constructor en setter are not very clear to me.

Comment: Are you sure you're using Firebug and not the [Firefox DevTools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools)? Because Firebug is officially discontinued and [doesn't work anymore starting from Firefox 57](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2017/10/saying-goodbye-to-firebug/).

Comment: @SebastianZartner Good catch! I'm using the FindBugs plugin. Will edit my question

Answer (score 4):

By calling `getImage()` you'll get access to the private field `image`. You can then modify it externally in any way you like, which might give you unwanted results.

You could circumvent it by having the getter return a *copy* of your underlying array. That way you can ensure the data's integrity.

So instead of

```
public byte[] getImage() {
    return image;
}
```

you can make use of `java.util.Arrays.copyOf(byte[] original, int newLength)`

```
public byte[] getImage() {
    return Arrays.copyOf(image, image.length);
}
```

I think that should get rid of that warning and be much safer to use, since your data is now protected from manipulation from the outside.

Comment: Thanks very much. It resolved the error on the getter. I edited my question, because I get the same errors on the constructor and setter.

Comment: @Urban Please [ask a new question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/188625/205238) instead of changing the old one.

Comment: Am i the only one finding this warning ridiculous, as it's just the way java works. There is no const or mut in the language. It's totally fine to "getList().add(2312)".